# The transaction associated with the current connection has completed, but has not been discarded

Tags: c#

I am using transactionScoped but this error is generated: The transaction associated with the current connection has completed, but has not been discarded. It must be downloaded before using the connection to execute SQL statements.

I already increased the time out but it still generates the error.

Comment: Put the relevant code that generates this error.

Comment: public DocumentQuery SaveModifyModify(DocumentQuery objDocQuery)
{
    _db.Entry(objConsultaDoc).State = objConsultaDoc.codigo == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();
    _db.Entry(objConsultaDoc).Reload();
    return objDocQuery;
}

The problem is generated in the saveChange but if I remove the transactionScoped it works fine

Comment: @JosueTo Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.